# Error 'glutTimerfunc' in C Opengl glut

Tags: c, opengl

While running a sample code from the internet, I am stuck at 'glutTimerfunc'. I cannot figure out what is this error.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you are setting function `frameTimerCallback`as the callback function, within that function itself. If the callback works it will tell glut to set the function is has already called back as the callback function...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide the relevant code and error messages in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glutTimerFunc` takes a pointer to a function that must have a signature of

```
void (*func)(int value)
```

Your `frameTimerCallback` function doesn't take an integer parameter. Hence the error.

Refer to https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html